# Change Fill Property of a path on pressed event

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, visualstatemanager

I have a border element which contains a path element and when the border is tapped I want to change the fill property of the path to another color.

I have searched for an answer but everybody seems to use control templates and styles (generally for buttons) for that kind of behaviour. Is there a way to change the color without using control templates and styles?

My code so far is as follows,

```
<Border>
    <Canvas Width="32" Height="32" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0">
        <Path x:Name="MyIcon" Width="30.5" Height="30.5" 
              Canvas.Left="0.75" Canvas.Top="0.750008" 
              Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="3" 
              StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" 
              Data="F1 M 15.9707,2.25001L 19.167,12.7919L 29.75,12.8197L 21.2578,19.1225L 24.4292,29.75L 16.0879,23.2829L 7.51911,29.6986L 10.831,19.2255L 2.25,12.7983L 12.7665,12.8177L 15.9707,2.25001 Z "/>
    </Canvas>
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
            <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ChangeCommand}"/>
        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MyIcon" 
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Path.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                    To="#FFFF0000" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
</Border>
```

Thanks for your helps in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your 'Pressed' `VisualState`, you are animating the `Color` property of the `SolidColorBrush` which is assigned to the `Fill` property of the 'MyIcon' `Path`. However, you haven't assigned a `SolidColorBrush` object to the `Fill` property of 'MyIcon'. Hence if you try to go to 'Pressed' state, it won't be able to find the `SolidColorBrush` reference and will throw exception. The simplest solution would be to assign `Fill="Transparent"` in your 'MyIcon' `Path`.
Also I'm assuming you have put your `Border` inside a `Control`, and you are calling `VisualStateManager.GoToState` in appropriate places.